# 'New-QADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PasswordNeverExpires'

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I continue to receive this error when running the script below.

```
New-QADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PasswordNeverExpires'.
```

I've loaded the active directory module and the quest active roles management console.

Removing the `-PasswordNeverExpires` parameter allows the script to work without any errors.

If anyone could shed any light on this I'd appreciate it.

```
$UserList=IMPORT-CSV C:\scripts\users.csv
FOREACH ($Person in $UserList) {
    $Username=$Person.vendorname+$Person.username.substring(0,0)
    $Description=$Person.description
    $Domain=’@domain.com’
    $UserPrincipalName=$Person.vendorname+$Domain
    $Name=$Person.vendorname+” “+$Person.username
    NEW-QADUSER –FirstName $Person.vendorname –Lastname $Person.username -DisplayName $Name       -Description $Description –SamAccountName $Username –UserPassword ‘Password' -PasswordNeverExpires $True –UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName  –Name $Name –ParentContainer ‘ses4energy.com/marketingportal/users’ 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `-PasswordNeverExpires` is not a parameter of [New-QADUser](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/New-QADUser).

You can use [Set-QADUser](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Set-QADUser) to set the "PasswordNeverExpires" flag.

```
New-QADUser –FirstName $Person.vendorname –Lastname $Person.username -DisplayName $Name -Description $Description –SamAccountName $Username –UserPassword ‘Password' –UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName  –Name $Name –ParentContainer ‘ses4energy.com/marketingportal/users’ | Set-QADUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```